# iTextSharp: Is there a way to override hard page numbers in a PDF?

Tags: itext

I have a document with a cover page, a table of contents, and then the actual content. The first page after the table of contents is numbered "1" in the footer.

Say the document has 130 pages, 128 pages of actual content aside from the cover and TOC. I want my audience to be able to go to the top of the adobe reader and see 1/128 rather than 1/130. When they enter 1, or 2 etc in that box, it jumps to page 1 or two of the actual content (rather than the cover page or the TOC). Is this possible?

Comment: Are these page numbers present in an existing PDF you want to modify, or are you generating the PDF from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get the results you're after with "Page Labels".

```
PdfPageLabels labels = new PdfPageLabels();
// label the first two pages "i" and "ii"
labels.addPageLabel( 1, PdfPageLabels.LOWERCASE_ROMAN_NUMERALS );
// label the following pages "1, 2, ..."
labels.addPageLabel( 3, PdfPageLabels.DECIMAL_ARABIC_NUMERALS );

myPdfWriter.setPageLabels( labels );
```

You can also give each page a unique string rather than page numbers:

```
labels.addPageLabel( pageNum, PdfPageLabels.EMPTY, pageNameStr );
```

I see "Page 1" in the text entry field, with (1 of 3) in the gray text next to it.  I don't think you can change the "of N", just that first part.

**Warning**:  I just discovered that the page "number" dialog in Acrobat X is limited to 8 characters.  Any label longer than that is impossible to enter.

Comment: This is the part where you mark you question "answered" by clicking on the check box next to my answer.  Folks searching for this question will see that its been answered and which one was correct (which isn't such a big deal when there's only the one answer, but is Quite Handy in the general case), and I get a little reputation.

Comment: Hah sorry I'm relatively new to the process. Done!